# Plotting time throws: OverflowError: int too big to convert

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

First I am converting pandas column from unix timestamp to datetime object. Then I am plotting it using matplotlib like this: (dividing by 1000 since timestamp is in milliseconds)

```
    pandas.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
    dataframe_tmp = dataframe
    dataframe_tmp["Open_Time"] = dataframe_tmp["Open_Time"]/1000.0 
    dataframe_tmp['Open_Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(dataframe_tmp['Open_Time'], unit="s")
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(dataframe_tmp["Open_Time"], dataframe_tmp["Open_Price"])
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
```

This works fine, but when I am trying to plot a point given time as x and float as y like this:

```
entry_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(i["entry_time"], "%H:%M:%S").time()
exit_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(i["exit_time"], "%H:%M:%S").time()
print(entry_time, exit_time)
plt.plot_date([entry_time, exit_time], [i["entry"], i["exit"]])
```

It thows this error:

> ```
>     np.timedelta64(int(np.round(x * MUSECONDS_PER_DAY)), 'us'))
> OverflowError: int too big to convert
> ```

entry_time and exit_time are the same format as the main chart:

> 23:56:00 23:59:00

However, if i remove **.time()** when converting the string to datetime it works, but entry_time and exit_time are formatted like this:

> 1900-01-01 23:37:00 1900-01-01 23:43:00

This makes all the points pushed to the left, and messes with the chart.

The datatype of the dataframe column is:

> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

The datatypes of entry_time and exit_time are:

> <class 'datetime.time'>

I am not sure what the error is, but I first thought it was because **entry_time** and the **dataframe column** needed to be the same type. However this does not make sense, as removing **.time()**  doesnt throw any error, but only messes with my chart.

What should I do to be able to plot the points on the chart correctly?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: as for me `plot_date()` is for ploting `dates` but you using `.time()` don't have `dates`, only `times`. Maybe convert `time` to normal string and use normal `plot()`